# How do I fill an object with a custom image in Javascript using Canvas on a moving object?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
var blobs = [];
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob(0, 0, 64);
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    var x = random(-width, width);
    var y = random(-height, height);
    blobs[i] = new Blob(x, y, 2);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  var newzoom = 64 / blob.r;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-blob.pos.x, -blob.pos.y);

  for (var i = blobs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    blobs[i].show();
    if (blob.eats(blobs[i])) {
      blobs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  blob.show();
  blob.update();
```

I want this "blob" to be filled with an image of a cell... How do I do that? My "blob" is currently solid white colour... Any help is appreciated as I don't even know where to start. Though the "blob" actually moves with the mouse like the popular game Agar.io.

```
var blob;

var blobs = [];
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob(0, 0, 64);
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    var x = random(-width, width);
    var y = random(-height, height);
    blobs[i] = new Blob(x, y, 2);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  var newzoom = 64 / blob.r;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-blob.pos.x, -blob.pos.y);

  for (var i = blobs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    blobs[i].show();
    if (blob.eats(blobs[i])) {
      blobs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  blob.show();
  blob.update();
}
```

Comment: What is this `Blob` class? It's obviously not [the native one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: @Thomas blob is the player, blobs are just dots that the player has to eat to get bigger.

Comment: Could you include your `show` method? If we know how you are rendering the blobs, it would probably be relatively easy to change the circle to an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas context [drawImage](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) method will let you render an image to the canvas in much the same way as you would draw a circle. You can specify x, y coords, width and height. Assuming that you currently render the blob doing something like:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(blob.pos.x, blob.pos.y, blob.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;
```

Then you could replace your code with:

```
var img = document.getElementById("cellImage"); //or however you want to get an img element
ctx.drawImage(img, blob.pos.x - blob.radius/2, blob.pos.y - blob.radius/2, blob.radius, blob.radius);//make sure your image is square, otherwise it will squish it weirdly
```

The reason we subtract `radius/2` from the coordinates is because the input coordinates are the top left corner, not the centre.
Alternatively, you said that the blob moves similarly to agar.io. This would suggest that it is always at the centre of the canvas, and everything moves relative to it. In this case, the code is even simpler, as you just need to render the image in the centre:

```
var img = document.getElementById("cellImage"); //or however you want to get an img element
ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width/2 - blob.radius/2, canvas.height/2 - blob.radius/2, blob.radius, blob.radius); //we just use the centre coordinates of the canvas instead of the blob coordinates.
```

Hope this helps!